# Podspec with dependencies to Google-Analytics Cocoapods 0.36

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I'm have a great issue with our private podspec, all worked fine until we updated to cocoapods 0.35.

The spec is not very complex, but is depended on the `GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK`
This is our pod spec:

```
{
  "name": "RKTagManager",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "summary": "Google TagManager wrapper.",
  "license": {
    "type" : "Closed Source",
    "text" : "This library is as is, not warrenty of any kind."
  }
  "platforms": {
    "ios": "5.1.1"
  },
  "requires_arc" : true,
  "source": {
    "hg": "<snip",
    "revision" : "RKTagManager-0.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK": []
  },
  "source_files": [
      "Source/RKTagManager/*.{h,m}"
  ]
}
```

When I try to validate it the compiling failed with the following message:

```
Ld /var/folders/9r/y21mxssd6rgf6gbrlhqsqv5m0000gp/T/CocoaPods/Lint/build/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-RKTagManager.build/Objects-normal/i386/RKTagManager normal i386
    cd /var/folders/9r/y21mxssd6rgf6gbrlhqsqv5m0000gp/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.1.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/<snip>/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk -L/var/folders/9r/y21mxssd6rgf6gbrlhqsqv5m0000gp/T/CocoaPods/Lint/build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods -F/var/folders/9r/y21mxssd6rgf6gbrlhqsqv5m0000gp/T/CocoaPods/Lint/build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods -filelist /var/folders/9r/y21mxssd6rgf6gbrlhqsqv5m0000gp/T/CocoaPods/Lint/build/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-RKTagManager.build/Objects-normal/i386/RKTagManager.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/RKTagManager.framework/RKTagManager -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.1.1 -framework Foundation -framework GoogleAnalytics_iOS_SDK -framework OIFoundation -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /var/folders/9r/y21mxssd6rgf6gbrlhqsqv5m0000gp/T/CocoaPods/Lint/build/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-RKTagManager.build/Objects-normal/i386/RKTagManager_dependency_info.dat -o /var/folders/9r/y21mxssd6rgf6gbrlhqsqv5m0000gp/T/CocoaPods/Lint/build/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-RKTagManager.build/Objects-normal/i386/RKTagManager
ld: warning: embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS 8 or later
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TAGManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RKTagManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I just don't understand why it can not find the TAGManager calls any more.
I'm using Xcode 6.2 and the the `RKTagManager` is ment for iOS.

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide details for the xCode version and the supported architecture. Thanks

Comment: I've added to the information.

Comment: I think the issue is that `GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK` spec links to google url but the old "library" is not present there anymore. There you can only find the new framework they are using.

Comment: I believe you have added a framework with only supports iOS 8 and above but you application deployment target is 5.1.1. Hence you have the issue. Also with 6.2 64 bit arch is compulsory. Please check for that too.

Comment: No the GooleAnalytics pod has support for iOS 5.1.1 and 64Bit is default.  This is not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution seem to be to force CocoaPods to build the pod spec with as a library. Since `0.36` the pods are build a framework and no loner as framework.

Use the `--use-libraries` to compile to pod spec as a library instant of a framework.

You can do this like:

```
pod repo push OIPods RKTagManager.podspec.json --use-libraries
```

Comment: Great solution got found an issue where my pod failed for   - ERROR | [MKDKit/MKDUIKit,MKDKit/MKDAnalytics] Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - NOTE  | [MKDKit/MKDUIKit,MKDKit/MKDAnalytics]  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)